# How to configure required navigation properties in EF Core

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, ef-code-first, nullable

I would like to use EF core with nullable reference types configured by fluent annotations.

I want to model a one-to-one relationship where `SomeEntity` has an `OtherEntity` called `Relation`, and `OtherEntity` optionally has a `SomeEntity`.

Because I don't want to always load the relation, I define OtherEntity as nullable, since it will be null if it's not loaded:

```
public class SomeEntity {
  public virtual OtherEntity? Relation {get;}
}
```

However, when I use this definition to build a model, `OtherEntity` becomes nullable in the database definition. That's not my intention: it should be required, in the database, just not necessarily loaded in the code.

How do I model this in such a way that it's clear the value could be null at runtime, but has a database backing store with a column that's not null?

I prefer not to adjust the code of the entity for this purpose, but if there is no other way, that will have to do.

Comment: The idea seems to be the opposite (non nullable navigation property, nullable backing field). It is discussed in the [Working with Nullable Reference Types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/nullable-reference-types) topic of the official EF Core documentation.

Comment: That page suggests to have a non-nullable reference type for relations that are not loaded, and throw exceptions when accessing the property if it is null. That's not what I want (nor, I think, what anybody would want when using nullable reference types -- preventing that is their whole point).

Comment: Well, that's what EF Core designers think. Since they are doing the EF Core, I don't see who can answer better your question. Btw, you can have NRT navigation property and still force it to be required using the `IsRequired` fluent API as it was before NRT.

Comment: My question still stands though: despite the EF Core designers thinking I would like to have a nullable reference type that could be null, I don't actually want that and would like to know how I can model a column with a NOT NULL constraint for a nullable reference type that could be null.

Comment: Btw, they are not only thinking, but they are **implementing** and enforcing specific behaviors, so if they decide to do it in a specific way, it doesn't matter what do you want. You can always implement your own ORM the way you want :) Fortunately this is not the case, so NRTs affect just the *default* behavior.

Comment: They are, of course, free to make decisions about default behaviours about modelling columns in a way that superficially doesn't seem to make sense, but my question is how to not have that default behaviour, but to get a NOT NULL constraint for an entity type that has a nullable relation.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/235979/discussion-between-martijn-and-ivan-stoev).

Comment: There is no way to change the *default* behavior. You can override the default behavior by configuring every navigation property fluently. Or decorate it with `[Required]` attribute. etc. The same way as you would make them required *before* NRT existed or when NRT is disabled. Nothing new here, not sure what's the question.

Comment: If there is no way to change from the default, it's not a default, it's the only way. But using the fluent API will work I think. I'll try it out.

Comment: Of course fluent API will work - I've mentioned it several times (`Has` + `With` + `IsRequired()`). Priorities are from lower to higher - conventions (default), data annotations (attributes), fluent API.